# wpf: How do I layout items horizontally and uniformly sized?

Tags: wpf, layout

What sort of control can layout child items horizontally and also uniformly resize the items to fit the available horizontal space? I'm replacing the "ItemsPanelTemplate" within a treeview template and a stackpanel will lay the items out in the correct orientation, but not resize them. A grid will only show the first child item in the treeview and lacks the support for reoriented horizontally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think just `<UniformGrid Rows="1"/>` will do what you want

Comment: Yes, UniformGrid does the trick, but you don't need the Rows=1.

Comment: Nice, and in my case, you do need Rows=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a uniformgrid in conjunction with a viewbox:

For example

```
<ViewBox StretchMode= "UniformToFill">
    <UniformGrid Cols="5">

    </UniformGrid>

</ViewBox>
```

Please pay attention to the different values of the StretchMode of the ViewBox, and also the number of element in a row of the uniform grid.  They depend on your data and  how you want to arrange elements.

Comment: I dont think ViewBox will work in this case, because it tranforms its content, not resize. So you will see things bigger than they are supposed to be.